# How to use installed fonts?

Tags: linux, fonts, xorg, i3-window-manager

I use fedora with i3-gaps and I want to use different font than monospace.

I donwloaded this realease of iosevka font [iosevka-term-ss01-3.0.0-rc.4](https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka/releases)
Then I coppied all .tff files to folders: `~/.local/share/fonts` and to the `/usr/share/fonts/iosevka`.
And at the end run command `$ sudo fc-cache -fv` to reload fonts.

Now the thing is how to put these fonts to use. I configure my ST terminal via [.Xdefaults](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/st/blob/master/.Xdefaults):

```
...
!! Set a default font and font size as below:
st.font: Monospace-10;

! st.termname: st-256color
! st.borderpx: 2
...
```

What should I write instead of `Monospace-10`?
I tried name of .tff file - text changed but to terrible form.
Maybe adding "config file" to `/etc/fonts/conf.d`?

Second question: How to add this font to the whole system?
Could it break possibly something (i3blocks)?

Thanks in advance for your answers

P.S. Bonus question: Has anyone clue how iosevka releases works? Which release/file should I use?

Comment: For fonts to be found automatically by applications, the locations must be `~.fonts/` or / and `/usr/share/fonts/TTF/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fc-list` to find font names, and make the st font line like so

`st.font: [font name]:pixelsize=[size];`

And about Iosevka: You want Iosevka Term.

Comment: Sounds good, but output of `fc-list` looks like this: `/usr/share/fonts/iosevka/iosevka-term-ss01-extrabolditalic.ttf: Iosevka Term SS01,Iosevka Term SS01 Extrabold:style=Extrabold Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/iosevka/iosevka-term-ss01-extendedmedium.ttf: Iosevka Term SS01,Iosevka Term SS01 MdEx:style=Medium Extended,Regular` What should I write as a font name? When I choose e.g. iosevka-term-ss01-extrabolditalic output looks terrible.

Comment: I figured it out: st.font: `Iosevka Term SS01 Extended:style=Bold Extended,Bold:pixelsize=14;`. I shouldn't write only the font name but also all that parameters around it include coma. Thanks for help